# locale error. cannot open locale definition file `fa_IR'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale

Here is my locale list:

```
locale -a
...
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
fa_IR
fa_IR.utf8
POSIX
```

I set `LC_ALL=fa_IR.UTF-8` with this command:
`export LC_ALL=fa_IR.UTF-8`
and when I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` I got this error:

> fa_IR.UTF-8... cannot open locale definition file `fa_IR': No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

I just did the following, and it is fixed.

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
sudo apt-get purge language-pack-fa
sudo apt-get install locales
sudo apt-get install language-pack-fa
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a locale called `fa_IR.utf8`, but you set `LC_ALL` to `fa_IR.UTF-8`.

Use the name of the locale that is installed, i.e. `fa_IR.utf8`, or install the appropriate packages that gives you the `fa_IR.UTF-8` locale on your system.